# Content inside tabbed content is automatically setting to display:none; so not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabbed

I am having a problem with some Tabbed content I have on a site i'm building.

I have some tabbed content, all tabs and function works fine and some HTML elements show, but others don't.

When viewing the source, I notice that the divs that don't show are being styled to `display:none`

I am not setting this myself. The CSS seems ok to me? Not sue why it would be doing this?

HTML:

```
<section class="main_content">
    <!-- <header><h2>Recent Snippets</h2></header> -->
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Sent Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Drafts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs_content">
        <div id="tab1">
            <header><h2>Inbox</h2></header>

            <article class="inbox_message">
                <div class="inboxavatar60x60">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"></div>
                <strong>This is a message Subject</strong>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet is simply dummy text of the typesetting industry. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>

            </article><!-- end aticle.inbox_message -->

        </div><!-- end tab1 -->

        <div id="tab2">
            <header><h2>Sent Messages</h2></header>

        </div><!-- end tab1 -->

        <div id="tab3">
            <header><h2>Drafts</h2></header>

        </div><!-- end tab1 -->

        <div id="tab4">
            <header><h2>Contacts</h2></header>

        </div><!-- end tab1 -->

        </div><!-- end tab_content -->

</section>
<!-- ***** END CONTENT MAINCONT ***** -->
```

CSS:

```
#tabs {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#tabs li {
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#tabs a {
position: relative;
background: #34495e;
padding: 0 15px;
float: left; 
height: 40px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fff;
line-height: 38px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#tabs a:hover, #tabs a:hover::after, #tabs a:focus, #tabs a:focus::after {
background-color: #69bd45;
color: #fff;
}
#tabs a:focus {
outline: 0;
}
#tabs #current a {
background: #69bd45;
/*background-image: url('../img/tab_arw.png') center bottom 9px;  */
z-index: 3;
color: #fff;
}
#tabs #current a::after {
background: #69bd45;
z-index: 3;
color: #fff;
}
#tabs_content {
background: #fff; 
padding: 20px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
#tabs_content header h2 {
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fa910a;
margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}


article.inbox_message {
width: 100%;
color: #ff0000;
}
article.inbox_message .inboxavatar60x60 {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
background-color: #647a91;
margin-right: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs_content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
$("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
$("#tabs_content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
$('#tabs li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
     return       
    }
    else{             
    $("#tabs_content div").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
    $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
    $( $(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
    }
});
});
```

Comment: you are using the `.hide()` function, this one is setting `display:none`

Comment: Yes, but surely that just hides everything that isn't in the open tab? Even when I open other tabs some html shows but other doesn't... You can see it in action at http://www.ozroyal.com/codesnipts/dashboard.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all the div elements inside your tab-divs are hidden,

i.e.

```
<div id="#tab2">
<div style="display:none">
</div>
<div style="display:none">
</div>
<div style="display:none">
</div>
.
.
</div>
```

You could add this line in your JS code, after you execute fadeIn()

```
$( $(this).attr('href')).find('div').show();
```

It un-hides each and every div tag, i.e. all **children** and **descendants**, so this snippet can be used only if there isn't any problem in un-hiding each and every div.

And also, when hiding tab content, just hiding the parent div is more than enough in most cases.